# Accessing array sent by server side js in the client js

Tags: javascript, express, nunjucks

I am learning expressjs,mongodb using nunjucks template.An array is sent from server to html in the following way:

```
poll.find().sort({'date': -1}).toArray(function(err,docs){
        res.render("home",{polls:docs});
    });
```

The variable polls is an array of objects.I am able to access the polls array successfully in the html view but I don't know a way to access it in the client side js file to draw charts using the data inside array.

If I use `<input type='hidden value='{{ polls }}'>`, it is converted to a string and the array, objects inside it cannot be accessed in client js. What can be done?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what nunjucks does, but express sends all non-scalar data (= objects & arrays) as an [JSON-string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

just use something like

```
var body = JSON.parse(responseText);
```

on the client to get the original object/array back.

Comment: Should we get 'responseText' from HTML? If so,the array of objects is converted to string and JSON.parse unable to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

To make it accessible correctly you need to output polls via `JSON.stringify` which will convert your javascript array to the json format: `JSON.stringify(polls)`.

So,

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ JSON.stringify(polls) }}" />
```

Or to access it in javascript:

```
<script>
    var polls = "{{ JSON.stringify(polls) }}";
</script>
```

Or it will be even better to do this operation on the server side to make it faster (instead of client-side):

```
res.render("home", { 
  polls: JSON.stringify(docs)
});
```

Comment: I tried `<input type="hidden" value="{{ JSON.stringify(polls) }}" />`, it gives **Error: Unable to call `JSON["stringify"]`, which is undefined or falsey**

Comment: For your 2nd suggestion script part, the 'polls' cannot be   accessed from the js file like we do in html, {{ poll }} not working.